# Is KeyCloak FIPS compliant?

Tags: keycloak, fips

We are going to use KeyCloak in one of our enterprise solutions. I would like to understand if KeyCloak is fully FIPS 140-2 compliant since we have compliance needs. There is very limited amount of information that I could find regarding this online. For example:-

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-October/003177.html

This is a pretty old link, so might not be updated with latest details.

If this is a wrong place to ask this question, kindly suggest the right one, if any. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, It does appear that in the past year there is a FIPS validated cryptographic module that can be used in KeyCloak (called [bouncy castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/)).

One of the issues is that there is no FIPS 140-2 compliant MFA option for Keycloak. It only supports Google authenticator and Free OTP apps).